# I have some changes in git master and branch so i want to push those changes accordingly in a single push

Tags: git, jenkins, github, gitlab

I have changed some code in git branch and master after cloning i made some changes in master and branch,then I want to push it to git in such a way that the changes made in branch should go to branch and changes in master to reflect to  master without specifying the branch  I want this to be done in a single step so I can automate my workflow using Jenkins and this is a migration task  .

Comment: And what is stopping you from pushing twice, from each branch?  Can you elaborate on what your actual problem is?

Comment: my requirement is to push at once so I  can automate this using jenkins

Comment: Then add more detail to your question.  If you had not commented, readers might have assumes you were trying to push two branches by hand from the bash or another Git tool.